# How do you delete a folder that contains spaces?

Tags: removing

So I finally got my Ubuntu box up and running, ran the LAMP install, and successfully loaded up the apache2 webserver, and php5.  The one thing I didn't want is for Ubuntu during the installation to take one whole 1TB drive that contained a ton of stuff, but it was a backup drive so no biggie.  But now I was transferring pics to the /var/www location and it copied a directory that contains spaces. Terminal seems to hang when I use the rm command, any ideas would be appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: What exactly do you add after the "rm"?

Comment: usually after the rm i enter angelo's Pictures, then i tried Angelo's\Pictures, and the terminal just went to a area where i could type in, hit enter but nothing would ever happend after that, and it stayed that way until I closed the terminal window.

Comment: Forgot to add I had to enter the root password since i used sudo... i just used the rm -r and double quotes and that did the trick.  Thanks for your response as well.

Comment: Ah, then I think I know what the problem was in the first place: the single quote in `Angelo's` is not seen as a character in the file name but as a special character. I bet that if you tried  `Angelo\'s\ Pictures` it'll work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your terminal hangs, that's very odd. In the terminal I'm usually able to remove spaces by escaping the space character with a backslash:

`rm -r test\ dir`

If that doesn't work, have you tried enclosing it in single or double quotes:

`rm -r "test dir"` or `rm -r 'test dir'`

Another idea would be to install a terminal file manager such as Midnight Commander and try to remove the file that way.
Good luck!

Comment: +1 but... `rm dirpath -r` works although it is undocumented, is at variance with the standard unix `command -options file ...` convention and just looks weird. It's probably better to keep to the standard habit. For example `awk /etc/passwd -F: '{print $1}'` yields an error (even though `cat /etc/motd -E` works).

Comment: Good call. The problem you mention seems not to exist for `rm -r`. I'll change my answer to make it a bit more neat.

Comment: haven't tried the double quotes, i will give that a try.

Comment: oh yeah, the double quotes worked like a charm, thanks guys.

Comment: Also you can press Esc or tab to match files. If you enter the start of the name and hit either, it will auto-match the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue that you had - 
i had 2 directories "push_apk_to Playstore/" & push_apk_to_Playstore/ , & i had to delete the directory push_apk_to Playstore/ 
I finally resolved the issue by applying a statement 
**`sudo rm -rf  push_apk_to\ Playstore`**
which successfully deleted the directory containing space .